# Is it possible to have a fixed menu with a SKScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible to have a fixed menu at the top of the screen with a SKScene?

[Simple sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWIiY.png)

It should be a menu and have the same size as the screen while the actual scene below can be scrolled if overflowing the screen.

Only one scene should have it so I can't put it in the controller which was my first approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches.

1. If your menu is something made from UIKit and you want it in the controller, you can still do that and just have a member variable that turns it on or off.
2. If your menu is made of sprite-kit views, just don't put it in the scrolling view and it won't scroll.  Add the menu and the scrolling view to the root view.

Comment: Thank you Lou! So simple that I missed it completely.